# Get Assembly Location of Referenced Method

Tags: c#, dll, configuration, mapping, .net-assembly

I have a DLL which is referenced by main application. When I call method from DLL I need to read configs from DLL-specific app.config file. However when I map Configuration Manager to required config file, I notice that GetExecutingAssembly() return assembly of the main app instead of referenced DLL. Is there a way to get exactly DLL assembly location when DLL is used? Of course, I would like to update my DLL so that it would always return its own assebmlylocation when executed.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Configuration libConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
       map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Comment: Have a method in the dll that returns `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Assembly`?

Comment: @stuartd it is unlikely to help - code show in in the post does about the same thing and would work fine *if executed by method inside DLL* (same as your sample). It is not clear where OP needs to run this code - so whoever will answer need to provide multiple options (including GAC-installed and shadow-copied cases)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good point, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Reflection to obtain it. There is the method GetAssembly that returning assembly containing passed type.

Example:

```
string s = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MemoryStream)).CodeBase;
```

returns path to mscorlib.dll:

"file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll"

Comment: this is a good thing, but still it returns path to local  copy of DLL in folder of main application. What I need is the path from where DLL was originally imported and where DLL-specific config file exists. Could there alternatively be a way to get the config of DLL when adding reference to DLL in main solution?

Comment: @KarenGumerov Why don´t you also copy the config-file to the bin-directory of your app? The assmebly doesn´t know *anything* of the location it might be copied from, in your case the project which it was compiled from including the config-file..

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a config-file for your assembly? Usually what you´re doing is to configure *apps*, not *libraries*. So users of program A may have these settings while users of program B have those, however both programs might use the same referenced assemblies.

Anyway if you really have to do this you can get the location of the referenced assembly you´re currently in using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`:

```
string assemblyPath = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Assembly.Location;
Configuration libConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
   assemblyPath);
```